# How to solve the error "Conversion to logical from optim.prob​lemdef.Op​t​imizatio​nC​onstrai​nt is not possible!" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, logical-operators

```
n = numel(daily_Ppv);
```

% VARIABLES

```
Ppvg = optimvar('Ppvg',1,n,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',daily_Ppv);     
Ppvb = optimvar('Ppvb',1,n,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',daily_Ppv);     
Pbe = optimvar('Pbe',1,n,'LowerBound',0,'Upperbound',Pemax);            
Ppve = optimvar('Ppve',1,n,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',daily_Ppv);       
Pelet = optimvar('pelet',1,n,'LowerBound',0,'UpperBound',Pemax);         
SOC = optimvar('SOC',1,n,'LowerBound',SOCmin,'UpperBound',SOCmax);
```

% CONSTRAINS

```
PowerFlow.Constraints.PPV = daily_Ppv==Ppvb+ Ppvg + Ppve;                     
PowerFlow.Constraints.PB = Ppvb*eta_pvb <= Pbmax;            
PowerFlow.Constraints.ELET1 = Pelet == Ppve*eta_pve + Pbe*eta_be;
PowerFlow.Constraints.ELET2 = Pelet <= Pemax; 
PowerFlow.Constraints.BAT = optimconstr(n);                
    for i = 1:n
        if Ppve(i) >= Pelet(i) %% this line reports the error
           PowerFlow.Constraints.BAT(i) = Pbe(i)==0;
        else 
           PowerFlow.Constraints.BAT(i) = Pbe(i)>0;
        end
```

Hi, I have met the following problem in MATLAB. The battery cannot charge/discharge at the same time so, in the last constraints, I tried to write this. When I ran the code the error says: "Conversion to logical from optim.problemdef.OptimizationInequality is not possible."

Appreciate for your help!

Comment: `Ppve` is not a value, but a "limitation Constraint". MATLAB is telling you it does not know how to compare those

Comment: If Ppve is not a value how do I change it? from the results of the optimization I would like that if the power coming from the PV is greater than what the electrolyzer can absorb then my battery charges up to 100% SOC, otherwise if the Pppve <Pemax the battery should intervene to power the electrolyzer.